# Trying to run echo server in Minikube with Istio getting connection refused from client socker

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I have a simple echo server (protocol TCP) written in CPP. I am able to put the server in docker container and with port mapping it works. So I think my client server are OK. When I upload the server image in Kubernetes and deploy Istio with ingress Gateway listening on port 31400 which I think is the right one when using tcp I get connection refused from client trying to connect to the socket.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: tcp-echo-deployment
    labels:
        app: tcp-echo
        system: example
spec:
   replicas: 1
   selector:
      matchLabels:
              app: tcp-echo
       template:
          metadata:
             labels:
                    app: tcp-echo
                    system: example
          spec:
            containers:
            - name: tcp-echo-container
              image: igordptx/my-tcp-server
              imagePullPolicy: Always
              env:
              - name: TCP_PORT
                value: "2701"
              - name: NODE_NAME
                valueFrom:
                  fieldRef:
                    fieldPath: spec.nodeName
              - name: POD_NAME
                valueFrom:
                  fieldRef:
                    fieldPath: metadata.name
              - name: POD_NAMESPACE
                valueFrom:
                  fieldRef:
                      fieldPath: metadata.namespace
              - name: POD_IP
                  valueFrom:
                   fieldRef:
                      fieldPath: status.podIP
              - name: SERVICE_ACCOUNT
                valueFrom:
                   fieldRef:
                      fieldPath: spec.serviceAccountName
                ports:
                   - name: tcp-echo-port
                     containerPort: 2701
```

`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
        name: "tcp-echo-service"
        labels:
                app: tcp-echo
                system: example
spec:
        selector:
                app: "tcp-echo"
        ports:
                - protocol: "TCP"
                  port: 2701
                  targetPort: 2701
```

I am new at this and I am trying to get a simple echo server to work. Attaching pictures of the YAML files of the Deployment,service,Gateway and virtual service for the routing.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
        name: echo-tcp-gateway
spec:
        selector:
                istio: ingressgateway
        servers:
        - port:
                number: 31400
                name: tcp-echo
                protocol: TCP
          hosts:
              - "*"


apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
        name: tcp-echo-vs-from-gw
spec:
        hosts:
             - "*"
        gateways:
             - echo-tcp-gateway
        tcp:
             - match:
                        - port: 31400
               route:
                        - destination:
                                 host: tcp-echo-service
                                 port:
                                        number: 2701
```

Comment: Need a little more info than YAML config. For example, did you check if the pod is running? There are n things that could go wrong from running your echo server in docker to deploying it with Istio. Why not create a simple deployment without Istio and test it?

Comment: Yes the Pod is running, all the pods and deployments are running and healthy. As I understand Kubernetes ingress cant handle TCP communication, but maybe I am wrong. Right now I am using clusterIp service to is isn't exposed to the outside world anyway.

Comment: Kubernetes Ingress is a skeleton API. It needs a third party controller to work. Istio provides this controller but there are stand-alone ingress controllers as well, e.g. nginx-controller or traefik. Both of these support TCP. I tried Istio on Minikube back in the day and it was hassle. Never used it again so can't comment on its current state. Besides, I think Istio works with VirtualService objects instead of Service. Not sure.

Comment: Hi, i would like to point out that istio is not fully compatible with minikube. Some istio features will not work.

Comment: Thank you, I got it to work kind of. The instio-ingress external IP was in pending mode, so I accessed the cluster from the node port. I seemed to work not sure why though. If someone has a good explanation ill be happy to hear it